# 'content' not Available for ui.Popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jointjs, rappid

Im using rappid for my current project.

Im trying to use ui.Popup for my element.
But for i don't know why, the 'content' option is not available for me. 
In the docs, it said it need the content option for the contents.
https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v3.4/ui.html#ui.Popup

But, when i press ctrl+space to see the available options, it doesnt have content. and if i add it manually, it just gives me error.

here's the picture, cant post picture coz its the first time i post a question: 
[https://i.ibb.co/nf6Zz1h/error.png][1]

Do i need to use other options that listed in the option? is the doc not updated?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was a TypeScript bug as the types were not provided for ui.Popup in version 3.4. It has been fixed in version 3.5, so you should not get the same error.

A temporary fix for version 3.4 is adding `//@ts-ignore` above the line where the TypeScript error is.